# Create results of a specific shape from MongoDB query/aggregation pipeline

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation

Consider this model:

```
const user = {
  firstname: { type: String, default: '' },
  lastname: { type: String, default: '' },
  goals: { type: Number, default: 0 },
};
```

And this collection:

```
[{
  id: 1,
  firstname: 'paul',
  lastname: 'pogba',
  goals: 2,
},
{
  id: 2,
  firstname: 'fred',
  lastname: '',
  goals: 2,
},
{
  id: 3,
  firstname: '',
  lastname: 'rashford',
  goals: 5,
},
{
  id: 4,
  firstname: 'luke',
  lastname: 'shaw',
  goals: 0,
}]
```

I want to perform a query (I guess it needs to be an aggregation pipeline) that returns an array where each available name in each matching document is an entry in the array. So using the example above, assume I want to get users with 1 or more goals. The final output of the query/aggregation pipeline would be:

```
['paul', 'pogba', 'fred', 'rashford']
```

Notice that

- the empty strings are excluded,
- both names are included if both are available in a given document
- `luke shaw`'s names are excluded because luke shaw doesn't match (has less than 1 goal).

I'm not even sure what MongoDB terminology is used for this so maybe that's why I'm not finding the right answers.

How can I achieve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `$match` `goals` is greater than 0
- `$group` all documents and prepare `firstname` and `lastname` array
- `$project` to make one `result` of array, `$filter` to iterate loop of array after concat `firstname` and `lastname` using `$concatArrays`, this will remove empty string
  from both array and concat in single result

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $match: { goals: { $gt: 0 } } },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      firstname: { $push: "$firstname" },
      lastname: { $push: "$lastname" }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      result: {
        $filter: {
          input: { $concatArrays: ["$firstname", "$lastname"] },
          cond: { $ne: ["$$this", ""] }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_0qtNLavtJp)